# mandrill, 14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: ssl, mailchimp, mandrill, whm

In mandrill webhook, I added https://xxxx/mandrills/email_bounced_back

The error I got is:

Error: POST to https://xxxx/mandrills/email_bounced_back failed: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I used https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker to check and seems ok (green)
I am using cPanel & WHM 64.0 (build 20)

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a renewed certificate. It was working with the old certificate... The Mandrill support don't know what is going on.